# Get tasks from a selected project

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to implement a many2one selection field where you select a project from. If you've selected a project then there's another many2one field where you can select the task from. These task all need to be from the selected project.

Currently I got this (note that I couldn't test it because I kept getting an XML error):

```
class purchase_order(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'purchase.order'

def get_task(self, cr, uid, ids, project_id, context=None):
    task_obj = self.pool.get('project.task')
    for task in task_obj.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
        task_ids = task_obj.search(cr, uid, [(task.project_id.id, '=', project_id)])
        ids_cus = []
        for cus in task_obj.browse(cr, uid, task_ids, context):
            if cus.project.id.id not in ids_cus:
                ids_cus.append(cus.project_id.id)
        self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state_readonly': 'listed', 'task_ids': [(6, 0, ids_cus)]})
    return True

_columns = {
    'project_id': fields.many2one('project.project', 'Project'),
    'task_id': fields.selection(get_task, 'Select task'),
}
```

And my XML looks like this:

```
   <record id="purchase_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">purchase.order.form</field>
        <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="origin" position="after">
                <field name="project_id" on_change="_get_task(project_id)"/>
                <field name="task_id" selection="widget"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

What am I doing wrong with the XML here? And might there be another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem, I've added a fields.related for chained fields:

```
    _columns = {
    'task_id': fields.related('project_id', 'tasks', type='many2one', relation='project.task', store=True,
                              string='Task')
}
```

And then adjust my XML (Like @Empiro Technologies said):

```
    <record id="purchase_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">purchase.order.form</field>
        <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="origin" position="after">
                <field name="project_id"/>
                <field name="task_id" domain="[('project_id','=', project_id)]"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to write method to filter tasks according to project in your case just change few things as follow.

```
class purchase_order(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'purchase.order'

_columns = {
    'project_id': fields.many2one('project.project', 'Project'),
    'task_id': fields.many2one('project.task', 'Tasks'),
}
```

and change your xml,

```
<record id="purchase_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">purchase.order.form</field>
        <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="origin" position="after">
                <field name="project_id" />
                <field name="task_id" domain="[('project_id','=',project_id.id)]" widget="selection" />
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

In your existing code you have made small mistake,

`selection="widget"` is not valid in xml you should write `widget="selection"`